# Elements corresponding to indices in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to obtain the array elements corresponding to specific indices. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1.1, 2.3, 1.9],[7.9,4.9,1.4],[2.5,8.9,2.3]])
Indices=np.array([[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]])
```

The desired output is

```
array([[2.3],[1.4],[2.5]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the columns of `Indices` separately. The first column for the row indices and the second for the column indices:

```py
out = A[Indices[:, [0]], Indices[:, [1]]]
```

Output:

```py
array([[2.3],
       [1.4],
       [2.5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

First loop through `Indices` to get the row and column index i.e. `i0` and `i1` respectively and then get the value in `A`. Use this:

```
output = np.array([[A[i0][i1]] for i0, i1 in Indices])
```

Output:

```
array([[2.3],
   [1.4],
   [2.5]])
```